# VSCode: Prevent split editor from resizing when focusing?

Tags: visual-studio-code

With multiple editor groups open, and one of them made small enough, focusing the small one causes it to get bigger until you switch back to another editor.  I'd prefer it leave everything at the size I set.
Is there a setting to prevent this?

Note how it has to be made small first
[image: new example]

[old example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hErM6.gif)

Comment: I think that is built-in behaviour that cannot be modified.  This might be the relevant issue:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73453

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't minimize the group all the way - you only have to stop just a tiny bit short of complete minimization (maybe only a pixel short) - then shifting focus between groups will not change their widths.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, vscode has a button split editor, which is enabled by the ctrl + \ hotkey. When i use it, the editor doesn't change the window size when i switched between the editors.

Comment: Oops, my gif doesn't show it well but this only happens when the editor is small enough. Try dragging the 'anchor' thing over to an extreme side first. Even using ctrl + \, the behavior still happens when it's small enough.