# How to disable resizing when focusing group in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When you click / focus another editor group, Visual Studio Code expands / resizes that group. How do we disable this behavior?

[image]

Comment: If you don't minimize the group all the way - stop just a tiny bit shy of minimum width - then the groups will not maximize upon focussing.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64934153/836330 - since that question was older and with some activity, i.e., not great answers - I answered it there.  So this is a duplicate of that.

Comment: Thanks. Kinda unrelated but do you know if there's a way to set the minimum width? I mean, change it.

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to adjust the minimum width.